# How to enable tracing for an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, trace

I follow the description in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.140).aspx to enable the tracing of my ASP.NET pages. But it does not work. If I call the trace viewer with `http://localhost/MyApp/trace.axd` then I receive the error that I should enable the trace flag in the web.config.

- I have verify that I edit the right web.config with changing "trace" to "trace2". This produce the expected error message.
- I have reduce the web.config to the max. I use only:

> ```
> <configuration>
>     <system.web>
>         <trace enabled="true"/>
>     </system.web>
> </configuration>
> ```

- I use Windows 8.1 with IIS 8.5.

What can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Are you accessing `Trace.axd` from the server or a client machine? Did you set `localOnly="false"`?

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Microsoft .NET Framework-Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET-Version:4.0.30319.34212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem. My application was only a virtual directory. Converting it in an application solve the problem. Another solution is to add the trace flag in the root of the IIS.

Answer (score 1):

try this setting:

```
<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true"  />
```

This setting will display tracing directly on page.

If you want to check trace.axd, make sure, that you are accessing it with the correct address.

Depending on your settings, address can look like:

```
http://localhost:<PORTNUMBER>/trace.axd
```

Comment: This would break my application because its corrupted the JSON data.